# Is there a way to reduce the radius of an image?

Tags: css

I've got an image, with properties defined as follows:

```css
.icon {
   background-color: white;
   border-radius: 50%;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
}
```

Due to the `border-radius`, the image is in a circle. Is there a way to tighten this circle by some number of pixels, such that some "outer layers" of the circle are shaved off, without scaling the image down with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of a few different ways to do this, depending on how "clean" you need this to be.  Read the comments in-line for a description of what is going on.

```css
/* Your code, as is: */
img {
   background-color: white;
   border-radius: 50%;
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
}

/* Using clip-path (not supported in IE/Edge): */
img.clipped {
  clip-path: circle(28.6% at 50% 50%);
}

/* Using a background image: */
span.image {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/150);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 25px #fff;
}

/* Using a span as a 'wrapper': */
span.image_wrapper {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 25px #fff;
}
```

```html
<!-- Your code, as is: -->
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />

<!-- Using clip-path (not supported in IE/Edge) -->
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="clipped" />

<!-- Using a background image: -->
<span class="image"></span>

<!-- Using a span as a 'wrapper' -->
<span class="image_wrapper">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="clipped" />
</span>
```

For clip-path see: https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20clip

Answer (score 4):

A combination of `background-size` and `background-position` properties allow you to resize an image as a background relative to the element it is a background of. Sorry if that is a mouthful, in other words, if this is your initial approach:

```css
.icon {
   background-color: white;
   border-radius: 50%;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://barkpost-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/grumpy-dog-11.jpg" class="icon" />
```

Instead if the image is applied as a background image you can control the size relative to the element:

```css
.icon {
   background-color: white;
   background-image: url('https://barkpost-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/grumpy-dog-11.jpg');
   background-position: center center; /* two values for horizontal and vertical positioning, you can use px or other units to configure distance too. */
   background-size: 180% 180%;  /* also two values for height and width, here I am using greater than 100% to make the image larger than the element, achiving the effect you are looking for */
   border-radius: 50%;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon" role="img" aria-label="this puppy looks a little closer, right?"></div>
```

Comment: I really like this idea - you could even remove the background colour and this would give a 'transparent' background!

Comment: Using images as backgrounds when they are semantically images doesn't feel right (at least for me), think about accessibility too. It may work using it as a background, but it won't be an "image" anymore, it will be the background of some box. You can make it work with a wrapper element without breaking the semantic of the content (you can add an `alt` attribute for screen readers for example).

Comment: @arieljuod I have updated the answer to include some additional attributes that should address any concerns you have about semantic HTML. more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Role_Img